# ios7 loops on the "trust this computer" dialog

Tags: linux, usb, ios, debian-wheezy

trying to transfer files to the work ipad via my debian7 box.

When i plug it on the computer usb port, it shows the dialog about trusting this computer, and the computer shows a gnome alert about the ipad being locked and that i should unlock it and try again.

i press "trust" on the ipad and try again on gnome.

and it starts again. over and over. endlessly.

there are dozen threads about this on apple support forums. no solution. just dozens of "me too" flags.

e.g. 
https://discussions.apple.com/message/23082859#23082859 (44 me-too, 2k views)

here is the log/messages i get

```
Oct 23 21:17:39 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1928.517766] usb 2-1.7: USB disconnect, device number 16
Oct 23 21:17:39 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1928.715441] usb 2-1.7: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci_hcd
Oct 23 21:17:40 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1928.811031] usb 2-1.7: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12ab
Oct 23 21:17:40 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1928.811036] usb 2-1.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 23 21:17:40 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1928.811039] usb 2-1.7: Product: iPad
Oct 23 21:17:40 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1928.811041] usb 2-1.7: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Oct 23 21:17:40 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1928.811043] usb 2-1.7: SerialNumber: fec5e0f6a6fa18a936de3c53af661051d290275e
Oct 23 21:17:40 dotmatrix mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 17: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7"
Oct 23 21:17:40 dotmatrix mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 17 was not an MTP device
Oct 23 21:17:43 dotmatrix kernel: [ 1932.346505] usb 2-1.7: USB disconnect, device number 17
```

If i never press the trust dialog it will stay there until i remove the cable. but the logs shows that it gave up 3sec after the cable was connected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known iOS7 incompatibility in `libimobiledevice` versions 1.1.5 and earlier.  It was [reported to the developers](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/20) and [subsequently fixed](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/pull/26).  The fix is [part of the 1.1.6 release](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/8e96f2af5960f4f5e4b52e4d7fe4e3c0ff2fe655/NEWS#L38).

I can personally confirm that I saw [the same problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1073003) under Fedora 20 with `libimobiledevice` 1.1.5.  Upgrading to [a test build](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2014-9092/libplist-1.11-2.fc20,libusbmuxd-1.0.9-2.fc20,libimobiledevice-1.1.6-2.fc20,usbmuxd-1.0.9-0.4.c24463e.fc20,ifuse-1.1.3-3.fc20,libgpod-0.8.3-2.fc20,upower-0.9.23-3.fc20,gvfs-1.18.3-3.fc20?_csrf_token=19462cd39594bbfd9c2340cd4b26fad2e145e213) of `libimobiledevice` 1.1.6 ought to fix the problem, but actually runs into some other [SELinux problems](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1073003#c14).

So assuming you don’t want to build from sources yourself, you need to convince your preferred Linux distribution to package, test, and ultimately ship `libimobiledevice` version 1.1.6 or later.